# Does invoking other contract constructor twice deploys the other constructor twice?

Tags: solidity

I am currently learning Solidity and I have found this example on internet for crowdfunding app in which it calls another contract constructor:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicensed

pragma solidity >0.7.0 <=0.9.0;
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract CampaignFactory {
    address[] public deployedCampaigns;

    function createCampaign(
        string memory campaignTitle, 
        uint requiredCampaignAmount) public
    {

        Campaign newCampaign = new Campaign(
            "campaignTitle1", 10000);
        

        deployedCampaigns.push(address(newCampaign));
        console.log("address of campaign: ",address(newCampaign));

        Campaign newCampaign1 = new Campaign(
            "campaignTitle", 1000);
        console.log("address of campaign1: ",address(newCampaign1));

    }
}


contract Campaign {
    string public title;
    uint public requiredAmount;

    constructor(
        string memory campaignTitle, 
        uint requiredCampaignAmount
    ) {
        title = campaignTitle;
        requiredAmount = requiredCampaignAmount;
    }

    function donate() public payable  {
        console.log("payable value: ",msg.value);
         requiredAmount += msg.value;
    }
}
```

I want to know that when we call the `createCampaign` function it creates two instances of `Campagin` contract twice with different values passed. When I have check the address of both the instances , they are different. So does it mean that `CampaignFactory` deploys the `Campagin` contract twice ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, each of them have their own unique contract address.